# handle exception while checking links using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check all the menu urls of a webpage by checking H1 element on the page. So when the loop runs and encounters an exception loop stops. I want the loop to continue even if it encounters a mismatch of css locator. please help

**here's my code**

```
    List<WebElement> dropdown = Driver.findElementsByXPath("//ul[@class='nav']//ul//li//a");
          int dropdown_count = dropdown.size();
          System.out.println(dropdown_count);

                   for (int i=0; i<dropdown_count; i++)
               {
                  String page = dropdown.get(i).getAttribute("href");
                              System.out.println(page);
                  Thread.sleep(2000);

                  Driver1.get(page);
                  try
                  {
                         Driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1")).isDisplayed();  
                  }
                  catch(NoSuchElementException ne)
                  {
                      System.out.println("error page: " + page);
                  }
                  {
                      System.out.println("page heading: " + Driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1")).getText());
                  }
}
```

Comment: I would put everything in the try clause, since it could fail on a number of lines.

Comment: @welsh: i tried it. not working

Comment: can you post the exception u are getting and moreover...is there reason behind 2 webdrivers in same test...other than just navigating to fetched url's

Comment: It is used to surpass login authentication. and this is the exception:
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h1"}

Comment: link will open and check for H1.. if found print the heading else print the error page and move on with the loop. The problem is that when H1 is not found the loop stops and throws an exception of css selector h1 not found

Answer (score 0):

### You have two major problems here:

**Problem #1 - An unhandled `NoSuchElementException`.**

The only statement in your code that can lead to that, is `Driver1.findElement(...)`.

You are executing this statement inside the `try` clause, but also outside the `try` clause.

So obviously, the loop (and probably the entire method) is terminated due to that exception.

Therefore, you need to move the second `Driver1.findElement(...)` into the `try` clause.

In fact, in the `try` clause, you might as well search for the `h1` element only once:

```
try
{
    WebElement h1 = Driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));
    if (h1.isDisplayed())
        System.out.println("page heading: " + h1.getText());
}
catch(NoSuchElementException ne)
{
    System.out.println("error page: " + page);
}
```

**Problem #2 - An unhandled `StaleElementException`.**

This exception usually occurs when you fetch some `WebElement` object, and at a later point in execution - after navigating to a different page using `get(...)`, or after switching to a different frame using `switchTo().frame(...)` - you attempt to use it.

This is what probably happens when you attempt to use `dropdown` after calling `Driver1.get(page)`.

Here is an optional workaround for this problem:

```
for (int i=0; true; i++)
{
    List<WebElement> dropdown = Driver.findElementsByXPath(...);
    int dropdown_count = dropdown.size();
    if (dropdown_count >= i)
        break;
    String page = dropdown.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    Driver1.get(page);
    ...
    Driver1.navigate().back();
}
```

---

And here is an alternative solution to both problems, that would make your program a lot more efficient. First, iterate all the links and build a list of URLs. Then, navigate to each URL and do whatever you wanna do on each page:

```
List<WebElement> links = Driver.findElementsByXPath(...);
List<String>     pages = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement dropdown : links)
{
    String page = dropdown.getAttribute("href");
    pages.add(page);
}
for (String page : pages)
{
    Driver1.get(page);
    try
    {
        WebElement h1 = Driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));
        if (h1.isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("page heading: " + h1.getText());
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException ne)
    {
        System.out.println("error page: " + page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it Not Working. 
I want the loop to check all the URL's and keep giving me exceptions in the console as and when it encounters a mismatch. I dont want the loop to stop.

Comment: Wait a second!!! You are calling `Driver1.get(page)` inside the loop. That can potentially turn any previous `WebElement` "stale" (leading to a `StaleElementException` as soon as you attempt to use it). And that's what probably happens when you attempt to use the `dropdown` after `Driver1.get(page)`.

Comment: I have put it inside the try block. Still when it encounters an error it stops!

Comment: But then I need it inside the loop to read the urls and open them one by one.

Comment: Please see revised answer

Comment: Added navigating back to the previous page at the end of the loop.

Comment: Added an alternative solution that would make your program a lot more efficient.

Comment: I tried your code..Loop stops at the page where exception is found. Still not working man.

Comment: There are two loops now (assuming that you've tried the alternative suggestion at the bottom of my answer). Which one of them breaks? What exception does it throw? Can you provide a few more details, printouts, etc?

Comment: The problem is not with the exception. It is just that the loop breaks if an exception is encountered which I dont want.

Comment: It is done. problem was with catch(nosuchelementexception) , I changed it to catch(Exception e). Now it works. Thanks a lot man:)